# Get user defined categories from Shared Mailbox in Outlook C#

Tags: c#, outlook, vsto, outlook-addin

I am working on Outlook add-in which would pull the list of pre-defined categories from shared mailbox. User then assign each email from shared mailbox to those categories.

My issue is I can get access to all categories linked to account using

```
Outlook.Application application = new Outlook.Application();
Outlook.Categories categories = application.Session.Categories;
```

but can't find a way to get categories linked to shared mailbox.

Is there any way to get shared mailbox categories? 
If not, how would I deal with this scenario, so later on I can create view based on those categories.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Categories are stored in a hidden message with the message class of "IPM.Configuration.CategoryList" in the store's Calendar folder. You can see it in [OutlookSpy](http://www.dimastr.com/outspy) if you go to the shared Calendar folder and click the IMAPIFolder button, then go to the "Associated Contents" tab.

That hidden message can be accessed using `MAPIFolder.GetStorage` in the Outlook Object Model.

You can also access the Categories collection in [Redemption](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption) (I ma its author) using [RDOCategories](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/rdocategories.htm) collection. Redemption exposes  categories both on the session level ([RDOSession](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/rdosession.htm).`Categories` from the default store) and on the store level ([RDOStore2](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/rdostore.htm#RDOStore2).`Categories`). A shared mailbox can be opened using `RDOSession.GetSharedMailbox`.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. So there is no way to retrieve categories without using OutlookSpy and Redemption?

Comment: I mentioned above that you can use MAPIFolder.GetStorage in OOM - OutlookSpy is just for you see where and how the data is stored.

Answer (score 0):

Following is the code to get Categories of selected folder.

```
public void LoadCategories()
    {
        CategoriesCombo.Items.Clear();
        Outlook.Application application = new Outlook.Application();
        Outlook.NameSpace ns = application.GetNamespace("MAPI");
        Outlook.MAPIFolder selectedFolder = application.ActiveExplorer().CurrentFolder;

        if (selectedFolder is Outlook.MAPIFolder)
        {
            Outlook.Folder folder = selectedFolder as Outlook.Folder;
            Outlook.Store store = folder.Store;
            Outlook.Categories categories = store.Categories;
        }
    }
```

If someone has better answer, I would look forward to see it.